# Wildcards and the MOVE command in a batch file - Wildcard not recognised as such

Tags: batch-file, syntax, wildcard

I have a batch file with the following line in it:

> move d:\cdr\C0*.%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%*.csv d:\CDRArchive\%yyyy%%mm%\

where the variables yyyy mm and dd are for their resective parts of a given date. When I run this, the batch file parses the variables out correctly, but I doesn't recognise the wildcard character *, so I get the following line:

> > move d:\cdr\archive\C0*.2013-09-08*.csv d:\CDRArchive\201309\
>   A duplicate file name exists, or the file
>   cannot be found.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It works fine, once the target folder is created.  Note that the error message you supplied shows that the filespec is wrong or the folder is wrong.  The error message you get when they are right is shown below. (tested in Windows 8)

```
d:\>move d:\cdr\C0*.2000-10-01*.csv d:\CDRArchive\200010\
Cannot move multiple files to a single file.

d:\>md d:\CDRArchive\200010\

d:\>move d:\cdr\C0*.2000-10-01*.csv d:\CDRArchive\200010\
d:\cdr\C0abc.2000-10-01.aaa.csv
d:\cdr\C0abc.2000-10-01.bbb.csv
d:\cdr\C0abc.2000-10-01.ccc.csv
        3 file(s) moved.
```

Comment: Now try it again, but use something like SET yyyy=2010, SET mm=10, SET DD=01 , and then use the variables in place of the dates in the move command. I have a feeling that wont work.

Comment: It will absolutely work with normal variables - there is no need to test it.  A reason it may not work though is if you set the variables within a loop, and don't use delayed expansion to use the variables within the loop.  Did the target directory exist with the date after running your batch file?